# link to two different web pages- HTML

Tags: html, hyperlink

Using HTML, I am looking for link codes that lead to open two pages:

- in two different taps of the same window
- in two tabs of a new window

In my code, I am able to open the pages in same page & new window:

```
<a href="http://www.page1.com" onclick="window.open('http://www.page2.com');">The link</a>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) this looks very spammy, and 2) You have to  use javascript to achieve this.

Comment: Well, yes you are correct somehow, but I hope I can achieve this using HTML.

Comment: The quoted window.open command within the onclick method is javascript. There is no way to get around that. You are calling a javascript function directly rather than your own javascript function that in turn then calls window.open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
<a href="http://www.page1.com" onclick="window.open('http://www.page2.com');window.open('http://www.page3.com');">The link</a>
```

You can separate commands in the onclick feature by a semicolon. They run sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="http://www.page1.com" onclick="window.open('http://www.page2.com');window.open('http://www.page3.com');">The link</a>
```

Comment: Yes. it really helped in how to think :)